# I need to identify this Unusual plant growing in pot in my garden

Tags: identification, annuals

[image]

It has green insignificant fluffy looking flowers growing all down the stem and each one now has a smaller version of the main leaves growing from it! The plant is only about 30 inches tall.   It is not related to the other green camelia growing in the same pot behind it.

Comment: Could you add few more photos? Maybe with a sheet of paper, so that we can see better what it is the plant, and what the background plant. Maybe a close up. Which soil did you use? [So do you think it the seed were on soil or on air?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that's an Amaranth - Amaranthus tricolor.

Native to Southeastern Asia into Africa, it's a perennial in zones 9b+ and is usually treated as an annual elsewhere. Propagation is via seed. Amanaranths like full sun to part shade and a moderately moist soil. In the garden, Tricolor can grow to 2-4 feet tall and 1-2 feet wide. Leaves and seeds are edible.

Here are some photos:

- http://mlb-s2-p.mlstatic.com/amaranthus-tricolor-sementes-flor-pra-mudas-8174-MLB20000697548_112013-F.jpg
- https://assets.listia.com/photos/8c30e6f2197d0c4386b8/original.png?s=800x600g&sig=7b320ca9b9525b4f&ts=1454606499

Comment: Yes, I am sure that this is the correct plant. I had this name somewhere in the back of my mind, but not quite sure of it.  You have been such a help, thank you.

Comment: Glad I could be of help! Please accept my answer so that we have it for future reference.